# How to execute a callback after `window.open`?

Tags: javascript, callback

I try to execute a callback after I opened a new window from JavaScript:

```
newwindow = window.open(myurl,'mywindow',false);

newwindow.onload = function() {
  console.log("callback");
  newwindow.console.log("callback");
}
```

However, the defined callback is neither executed in the parent, nor in the child window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

when '_parent' passed as the second argument ,it loads `myurl` in the parent frame

so this page that you're in will be closed and rest of script won't be executed

if you want to open it in new window use this instead:

```
newwindow = window.open(myurl,'_blank',false);
```

Comment: that is true, but it is not what the question was about

Comment: my answer was for the first edit :D
this edit works just fine. if it doesn't,check that `myurl` and your parent window has the same domain